# Purchase event does not hit correctly

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Purchase event in GA4 sometimes work sometimes not. I checked it in free form report that only few transactions are coming in the report but most of the transaction are missing and thus Google analytics4 shows incorrect Revenue. Please help me to correct the purchase event and the transactions.

Comment: The problem is on how are you tracking the revenue? Do you install Google Tag Manager and GA4 tag to track? Or you just installed the gtag code to track?

Comment: Yes I have added datalayer code and implemented GTM, also I have added 2 purchase event one for universal analytics and one for GA4 and the name of the event is 'purchase' for both the events.

Comment: So you can : 1. Preview your GTM for your webite. 2. Make a test order. 3. Screenshot about GTM preview about ```datalayer```, ```tag firing```, ```ga4 hit``` as mush as you can. Then maybe we can find out what happen.

Comment: Thanks @Darrellwan for the help. Please check below screenshots.
The Total transaction showing in GA Dashboard: https://ibb.co/8XLsx7q
but the total transaction in admin dashboard for the same duration : https://ibb.co/4tVnytz
GTM Tag :  https://ibb.co/9r8fVbc
GTM Trigger: https://ibb.co/mFZyTCy
GTM Tag fired: https://ibb.co/QYvTzdd
GA4 not detected ‘purchase’ event: https://ibb.co/9NGGph6
Product Array: https://ibb.co/KwsNZbT
GTM variable inside code(gtmGAData): https://ibb.co/XFVCmhJ
DataLayer Push code for thankyou page: https://ibb.co/rynZr4d

Comment: Also, sometimes the ‘purchase’ event appear in the GA4 test extension but sometimes not like uploaded above so it can be the case that GA4 is not detecting the event properly.

Comment: There is a different way when Google tracking UA and GA4. Sometimes GA4's hit will be delay and combines other event together! In your case. When you finished the order, the purchase datalayer is as quick as pageview. You might want to wait a minute then you will see the hit in the extension.  The most accurate way to check is open your preview mode in GTM and see if the tag fire or not. Extension is just another 3rd party tool to assist. Not 100% accurate.

Comment: I can see the tag in GTM preview. Let me try to add the data layer code after the page is loaded completely inside document ready function. Hope it should work then. Thanks Darrellwan

Comment: Hello @PoojaShreeSingh ! 
I am having the same issue. I got less 20% of transaction orders on GA4 compared to UA. Did you found a solution?
Thanks